# Merging two columns using cross function in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to merge two columns using cross function which i need to use later for further analysis.

Inpout Data

```
id_number  company_name        match_acc

IN2231D    AXN pvt Ltd
UK654IN    Aviva Intl Ltd
SL1432H    Ship Incorporations
LK0678G    Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd
NG5678J    Nokia Inc


identity_no   Pincode   company_name

 IN2231        110030    AXN pvt Ltd
 UK654IN       897653    Aviva Intl Ltd
 SL1432        07658     Ship Incorporations
 LK0678G       120988    Oppo Mobiles Pvt Ltd
```

I am looking out to merge the column id_number with identity_no

Code i am using so far:

```
cross = df1[['id_number']].merge(df2[['identity_no']], how='cross')
```

But Getting the error:

```
pandas.errors.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False
```

Output what i need:

```
#    id_number identity_no
# 0    IN2231D      IN2231
# 1    IN2231D     UK654IN
# 2    IN2231D      SL1432
# ...
# 17   NG5678J     UK654IN
# 18   NG5678J      SL1432
# 19   NG5678J     LK0678G
```

Please suggest.

Comment: what is your `pd.__version__`. My guess is it's <1.2.0 so you need to upgrade, or if you can't you need to create the helper column yourself and merge

Comment: Pandas version : 1.1.3

Comment: @ALollz does the newer version of pandas create the helper column for a cross join? pretty cool, didn't know that! thanks.

Comment: @ALollz - How the helper column can be created, and how to perform merge operation later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`how='cross'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

This was a feature introduced in `pd.__version__ == '1.2.0'` so if you have an older version of pandas it will not work. If for some reason you cannot upgrade you can accomplish the same with the use of a helper column that is the same constant for both DataFrames that you then drop.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'y': ['a', 'b']})

# For versions >=1.2.0
df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
#   x  y
#0  1  a
#1  1  b
#2  2  a
#3  2  b

# For older versions assign a constant you merge on.
df1.assign(t=1).merge(df2.assign(t=1), on='t').drop(columns='t')
#   x  y
#0  1  a
#1  1  b
#2  2  a
#3  2  b
```